# Stored Procedure in PostgreSQL (Aggregation)

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am using PostgreSQL and my table columns are as follows. I need to come up with a Stored Procedure along with two input parameters.

1. id
2. phonenumber
3. start_time
4. end_time
5. orgid (input param)
6. orgName
7. customer_type (input param)

My expected output is

"totalCalls":12000,
"todaysCalls":520,
"lastDayCalls":888,
"currentMonthCalls":865210

Business logic:

Here orgid and customer_type fields are optional as in where conditional parameters

1. totalCalls = Count all the records from this table
2. todaysCalls = Count all the records from this table comparing between start_time column and current date e.g.  WHERE ((date(c.start_time) >= date(current_date))
3. lastDayCalls = Count all the records from this table comparing between start_time column and current date interval e.g. WHERE ((date(c.start_time) = date(current_date - interval '1 day'))
4. currentMonthCalls = Count all the records from this table for current month.

Note:
orgid and customer_type column value can be evaluated for above each condition.

Thank you!

Comment: According to your description totalCalls should be > currentMonthCalls...

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.